# onesignal plugin initialization

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

Hello I am facing problem during onesignal init, please help how to solve this error. I can't find anything related to onesignal in my config.xml file. I installed onesignal plugin in my ionic app as per documentation provided and it installed successfully.

I am developing Ionic app on android platform.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few troubleshooting steps that could help resolve this issue:

1. Double check that you have followed all of the OneSignal setup
   instructions for your platform correctly.
2. Take a look at your
   application log to see if there are any errors explained there.
3. Take a look at the troubleshooting guides here https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/known-issues.

Comment: I have checked all documentation..troubleshooting steps provided on onesignal docs. Nothing helped me. Main problem is, not getting push notifications even after device registered and subscribed (As shown in my Onesignal Dashboard).

PS: onesignal init error is in browser (Ionic Serve). I dont think this error exists in real device.